# Whats wrong with my server code(c++)

Tags: c++, client

I am almost finished making this server but before I finished it I wanted to test it, but when I do it keeps on saying "connection was reached" before anyone connects to it. I want it to say, "connection was reached" when someone actually connects to it. any help?

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   WSAData wsa;

   int iresult =WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &wsa);

   SOCKADDR_IN Server;

   Server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

   Server.sin_family = AF_INET;

   Server.sin_port = 6667;

   SOCKET Listen =(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

   listen (Listen, SOMAXCONN);

   bind(Listen,(SOCKADDR*)&Server,sizeof(Server));

   SOCKET Connect =(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

   int size = sizeof(Server);

   std::cout<<"Waiting for connections";

   for(;;)
   {
    if(Connect=accept(Listen,(SOCKADDR*)&Server,&size)) {
        std::cout<<"connection was reached";
        break;
        }
    }


  WSACleanup();

  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SOCKET Listen =(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);` and `SOCKET Connect =(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);` don't really make sense in this context. Maybe they should be calls to [`socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson so should I get rid of it and if I should then what do I do instead?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you probably mean to write `SOCKET Listen =socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I fixed it. do you see anything else wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

One problem is here:

```
Server.sin_port = 6667;
```

The port number must be in network byte order, which is opposite of the byte order of the common x86 platform. Instead do

```
Server.sin_port = htons(6667);
```

There are also many other problems with your code, like for example the ones pointed out in the comment by Joachim Isaksson.

There is also this:

```
if(Connect=accept(Listen,(SOCKADDR*)&Server,&size))
```

You have to remember that `accept` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` (or `-1`) on error, which is "true"

Comment: so are you saying that if(Connect=accept(Listen,(SOCKADDR*)&Server,&size)) shouldn't be there or what? and if it shouldn't, what should? this is so confusing

Comment: @user2626734 I'm saying that the condition will be true for *both* correct accepts *and* when there's an error. Call `accept` first, then check for errors separately, it might be easier for you.